# Are there common "environment" variables in IBM Cloud functions (actions)?

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I am writing a number of actions (IBM Cloud functions,) which share a couple of the same parameters, e.g. the IAMAuthenticator or the database path. Is there a way to set these as some kind of environmental variables common to several functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of packages and [bind those variables to a package](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-actions#actions_pkgs_params). All actions in a package kind of share the same setup. It is a way of organizing and simplifying deployment.